# How to enter Double values in case statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, double

I used to check int values in case statements but is there any way check double values too? I can't use If else. This is an assignment. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141830/switch-expression-cant-be-float-double-or-boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `double` values provide an exact representation only in case when the value can be expressed as a sum of powers of 2 that located "close enough" to each other (within the length of mantissa), and because `switch` works only with exact matches, you cannot use `double`s in a switch in a general case.

The basic reason for it is the same as the need to be careful when using `==` to compare `double`s. The solution is the same as well: you should use a chain of `if`-`then`-`else` statements to find the desired value

```
if (a <= 0.2) {
    ...
} else if (a < 0.5) {
    ...
} else if (a < 0.9) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

or use a `TreeMap<Double,Something>` and perform a limit search:

```
TreeMap<Double,Integer> limits = new TreeMap<Double,Integer>();
limits.put(0.2, 1);
limits.put(0.5, 2);
limits.put(0.9, 3);
...
Map.Entry<Double,Integer> e = limits.ceilingEntry(a);
if (e != null) {
    switch(e.getValue()) {
        case 1: ... break;
        case 2: ... break;
        case 3: ... break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, but it won't perform very well. This will work

```
// don't do this, unless you want readability not performance.
switch(Double.toString(d)) {
   case "1.0":
        break;
   case "Infinity":
        break;
}
```

Instead you should use a series of if/else statements or use a `Map<Double, DoubleConsumer>` for a long list of doubles.

You can use a NavigableMap for efficient range searches.

```
NavigableMap<Double, DoubleConsumer> map = new TreeMap<>();
// default value is an assertion error
map.put(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, d -> new AssertionError(d));
double upperBound = 12345;
map.put(upperBound, d -> new AssertionError(d));

// if >= 1.0 then println
map.put(1.0, System.out::println);


public static void select(NavigableMap<Double, DoubleConsumer> map, double d) {
    Map.Entry<Double, DoubleConsumer> entry = map.floorEntry(d);
    entry.getValue().accept(d);
}
```

Comment: Actually I have an assignment to do this.. Thank you.

Comment: @user126494 in which case, readability may be more important than performance.  Note: with double you are likely to need rounding or range searches.  You can implement range searches with a `NavigableMap`

Comment: Can you please explain NavigableMap with an example.. I'm really new to that.

Answer (score 0):

Switch cases only take byte, short, char, and int. And a few other special cases.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html